# Replace single element of a nested list with multiple elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I wonder how to replace specific element (even though repeated)  within sublists of a nested list with multiple elements while maintaining the list structure. Suppose the following:

```
{{{{O1, 2, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14, D1}, {O1,
     1, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, D1}, {O1, 2,
     22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14, 13, D1}, {O1, 
    2, 22, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, D1}, {O1,
     2, 1, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, D1}, {O1,
     1, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, 14, 
    D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14,
     D1}, {O1, 1, 2, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14,
     D1}, {O1, 2, 22, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 
    13, 14, D1}, {O1, 2, 1, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 
    27, 13, 14, D1}, {O1, 2, 1, 21, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, 
    PoP2, 18, 28, 14, D1}, {O1, 1, 21, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17,
     PoP2, 18, 28, 14, 13, D1}, {O1, 1, 2, 22, 24, 6, PoP1, 5, 23, 27,
     17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14, 13, D1}, {O1, 1, 2, 22, 21, 23, 5, PoP1, 6,
     24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, D1}, {O1, 2, 1, 21, 22, 24, 6, 
    PoP1, 5, 23, 27, 17, PoP2, 18, 28, 14, 13, D1}, {O1, 1, 2, 22, 21,
     23, 5, PoP1, 6, 24, 28, 18, PoP2, 17, 27, 13, 14, D1}}}}
```

I would like to substitute PoP1 with XXX,YYY,ZZZ and PoP2 with SSS,FFF while having the same list depth and sublists. 
I have tried with /. but it introduces a new sublist like :

```
{{{{O1, 2, 22, 24, 6, {XXX, YYY, ZZZ}, 5, 23, 27, 17, {SSS, FFF},
     18, 28, 14, D1}, {O1,...
```

Comment: Have a look at `Sequence`.

Comment: You were right, just use sequence and is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a minimal working example that you can adapt to your needs:

```
{{"x",1,3},{2,4,"z"}}/.{"x"->Sequence@@{"a","b"},"z"->Sequence@@{"c","d"}}
```

produces:

> {{"a", "b", 1, 3}, {2, 4, "c", "d"}}

Answer (score 0):

making use of /. with element->Sequence[element1,element2] actually does it.